# Add authentication headers to native video element

Tags: vue.js, authentication, video-streaming, html5-video, video.js

I am using [videojs-player](https://github.com/surmon-china/videojs-player) for Vue in order to display videos fetched from my backend application.

I use Django REST Framework (DRF) on the backend (server-side) and a Vue SPA on the frontend. My app achieves authentication by obtaining a token at login time; axios sends that login as an authorization header in every subsequent requests made by the frontend

**Problem**: 
One problem I'm facing is that authentication is required in order to access the videos on the backend; which is achieved application-wide by using a bearer token authentication header.

videojs-player internally uses a native `<video>` element, which just takes a `src` url and makes a request to get the video.

This of course results in a 401 response as no authentication is provided.

Is there a way to inject the appropriate header in this situation?

Comment: Is using PHP an option? If yes and all other options are not working... Just use PHP as a middle-man (or proxy) for making the request. Basically, the video tag's own GET request will receive data from the PHP script (where data is first returned to PHP after it authenticates, then same PHP streams it back to the video tag). This means you set the `src` as **video1.php** instead of example of **video1.mp4** and so when the video tag makes a GET request towards the `src` the PHP file will be run to make the authentication by itself then return the results (file bytes) back to the requester.

Comment: I am not using php

Comment: **(1)** _"I am not using PHP"_ Do you think that's enough side information to get help for **fixing a technical issue**? Better to tell me **what you are actually using** then, to do these server-side authentications (_eg:_ mention if it a JS-based `Fetch` request or whatever other method)?... Maybe I should have worded it as _"Is using some **server-side** language like PHP an option?"_  (meaning Python, Ruby, Rust, C# etc are also valid options to achieve the same results of my above comment)...

Comment: **(2)** Assuming you're using only a JS function to authenticate, here the simplest/fastest thing you could try is using the function itself as the `src` of video tag: `<source src = "my_Authenticate_function()">` (make sure **this function returns something**, either gives back a string of the file's URL or else it gives back the bytes/data of the requested file itself)...

Comment: Apologies for not being able to read your mind. I use DRF on the backend and a Vue SPA on the frontend. Therefore, no chance on doing the HTML rendering on the server. My app achieves authentication by obtaining a token at login time; axios sends that login as an authorization header in every subsequent requests made by the frontend

Comment: The information is better now... I don't use Python/Django but will suggest from experience with video tag expectations... Try putting this in a function `let result = await axios.get('https://your_path_to_file', { headers: { 'Token': 'your_token_here' } }); return result;` and then use that function as `src` for video tag (PS: I predict seeking might not be available, but for now just try getting any playback or first frame showing)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** This current method (of client-side accessing the file) means you have to wait for the file to fully download before you can play it. Unless you know how make Axios "stream" a file (packet by packet)?.

The best solution would be to actually do the file reading part using a server-side script (*eg*: a PHP script). This means after being logged-in and getting the token, you pass that token and expected file name as a URL variable. The request URL points to a script file which has instructions to check if provided token is valid and then return the mentioned video file.

pseudo-code JS example: `video.src="myScriptFile?token=XXXX&file=video1.mp4"`

**Without using any server-side scripts:**

Below is a code example to load video data from Axios into a video tag.
For testing, modify the file paths to use your own (or just test at: [W3Schools Editor](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video_all)).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<video id="myvid" width="640" height="400" controls>
<source src="null.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"> </script>

<script>

var path; var vid_1; var vid_2;
var myvid = document.getElementById("myvid");

//# testing file paths
vid_1 = "https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"
vid_2 = "https://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4";

//# test axios function with some file path
getvideo( vid_1 );

function getvideo ( input_filepath )
{
    axios.request(
    {
      responseType: 'blob',
      url: input_filepath,
      method: 'get',
      headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'video/mp4',
                    'Token': 'your_token_here'
                }
    }).then( 
                (result) => {
                                //alert( "data : " + result.data );
                                path = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL( result.data);
                                myvid.src = path;
                                myvid.load(); 
                                //myvid.play();
                            }
    );
    
    //# do anything else here...???
    
    
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```