# Angular video_url doesn't show the file after uploading the video file

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, video, html5-video

I have build a uploading Video process in my ionic 5 Angular 12 project. The process works fine, the video is uploading and show a corrupted video file as in the photo i attached.

I want to make a preview of the video that the user has uploaded, but the video url seems to be broker and doesn't show the file as i've shown the attached screenshot.

[image]

here is my code

html
BUTTON TO START THE UPLADING
<ion-fab-button color="danger" (click)="chooseVideo()"

```
 HTML5 VIDEO TAG TO SHOW THE UPLOADED VIDEO
<video webkit-playsinline="true" playsinline="true" class="cover-video" controls id="video" (click)="toggleVideo()" 
    webkit-playsinline #videoPlayer preload="auto">
        <source [src]="video_url" [type]="'video/webm'" *ngIf="checkExtension(video_url,'webm')">
        <source [src]="video_url" [type]="'video/mp4'"  *ngIf="checkExtension(video_url,'mp4')">
        <source [src]="video_url" [type]="'video/ogg'"  *ngIf="checkExtension(video_url,'ogg')">
    </video>
```

.ts

```
video_url: string = '';

async chooseVideo() {
    const actionSheet = await this.actionSheetCtrl.create({
        header: this.translation.select_video_source,
        cssClass: 'actionSheetButton',
        buttons: [
            {
                text: this.translation.Use_Camera,
                cssClass: 'uploadVideoButton',
                handler: () => {
                    this.captureVideo();
                }
            },
            {
                text: this.translation.Cancel,
                role: 'cancel'
            }
        ]
    });
    actionSheet.present();
}

checkExtension(file: string, type: string) {
    return this.userData.getFileExtension(file) === type;
  }
```

FUNCTION TO CAPTURE VIDEO FROM CAMERA

```
captureVideo() {
    const options: CaptureVideoOptions = {
        limit: 1,
        duration: 30
    }
    this.mediaCapture.captureVideo(options).then((res: MediaFile[]) => {
        let capturedFile = res[0];
        this.video_url = capturedFile.fullPath;
    }, (err: CaptureError) => console.error(err));

}
```

function to play video_url

```
playVideo() {
    let options: StreamingVideoOptions = {
        successCallback: () => { },
        errorCallback: (e) => { console.log('Error streaming') },
        orientation: 'landscape'
    };
    this.streamingMedia.playVideo(this.video_url, options);
}
```

**Problem**:

Is it possible I am doing something wrong with path? Shouldn't `video_url` show the video file?

This is the error I am getting after `console.log(res[0])` :

```
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/VID_20221205_130100.mp4
```

Other useful log details :

```
MediaFile   {
                name: 'VID_20221205_130100.mp4', 
                localURL: 'cdvfile://localhost/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/VID_20221205_130100.mp4', 
                type: 'video/mp4', 
                lastModified: null, 
                lastModifiedDate: 1670238065000, 
                …
                
            }
            
            end: 0
            fullPath: "file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/VID_20221205_130100.mp4"
            lastModified: null
            lastModifiedDate: 1670238065000
            localURL: "cdvfile://localhost/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/VID_20221205_130100.mp4"
            name: "VID_20221205_130100.mp4"
            size: 7316613
            start: 0
            type: "video/mp4"
            
            [[Prototype]]: File
            app/tablinks/upload:1
```

Thanks

Comment: **(1)** Use `console.log` to check what data type you've got in `res[0]` or even in `res` itself. **(2)** I don't use Angular but for path try `this.video_url = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL( res );` (adjust as needed, maybe it's actually `( res[0]  )` to use? In Javascript the **res** part would be an array of video bytes or a user-selected file

Comment: PS: See [my JS-based Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74577040/add-authentication-headers-to-native-video-element/74649975#74649975) but it should give you a starting idea. Let me know the result of point **(1)** from the above comment

Comment: Thanjks VC One. I updated to show the error i am getting after console.log(res[0])

Comment: **(1)** Can you get away with using : `cdvfile://localhost/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/VID_20221205_130100.mp4` as the video url? **(2)** See if [these Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23784480/2057709) help you to load a local file... **(3)** The problem is you cannot use `file://` with HTML Media Elements. You have to find a way to get the data before it's written as file (while it is inside app memory) and then play it as a "blob" object, if it is already saved then the user must first select the file (thru some file-browser popup) to show they give permission for file access.

Comment: No it seems that you cannot use cdvfile://localhost/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/VID_20221205_130100.mp4. Do you have an example of what to use in my case?

Comment: Try the [File-Transfer plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/reference/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/). See the first example code, it loads a text file from `cdvfile://localhost...etc`. See if it can load your MP4, so do a console log of the array size (`myArray.length`) after loading to confirm you have some bytes. Then you can try my top comment (just replace `res` with your array)

Comment: PS: The [download link](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer). Even though it says deprecated, try to install it somehow because the newer replacement ([XMLHttpRequest](https://cordova.apache.org/blog/2017/10/18/from-filetransfer-to-xhr2.html)) won't load local files. You can even see the HTTP in the name.